# If the roots of $ax^3 - x^2 + bx - 1$ are real and positive, prove $b \geq \sqrt{3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let

$$p(x) = ax^3 - x^2 + bx - 1$$

such that $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and the roots of $p(x)$ are real and positive.

Prove that

$$b \geq \sqrt{3}$$

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$ be the roots of $p(x)$

$$\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \sigma_1 = \frac{1}{a}$$

$$\alpha\beta + \beta\gamma + \gamma\alpha = \sigma_2 = \frac{b}{a}$$

$$\alpha\beta\gamma = \sigma_3 = \frac{1}{a}$$

Consider the inequality:

$$\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 \geq \alpha\beta + \beta\gamma + \gamma\alpha$$

Since the inequality is cyclic, we may assume $\alpha \geq \beta \geq \gamma$. Now, the above is clearly true by the rearrangement inequality.

$$\implies \sigma_1^2 - 2\sigma_2 \geq \sigma_2$$

$$\implies \sigma_1^2 \geq 3\sigma_2$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{a^2} \geq 3\frac{b}{a}$$

$$\implies 1 \geq 3ab \tag{1}$$

Now, from the AM-GM inequality:

$$\alpha + \beta + \gamma \geq 3\sqrt[3]{\alpha\beta\gamma}$$

Since $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \alpha\beta\gamma$,

$$\alpha^3\beta^3\gamma^3 \geq 27\alpha\beta\gamma$$

$$\implies \alpha\beta\gamma = \frac{1}{a} \geq 3\sqrt{3}$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}} \geq a$$

Putting this in $(1)$, we get:

$$3ab \leq \frac{b}{\sqrt{3}}$$

We know that $3ab \leq 1$, but we can't say that $\frac{b}{\sqrt{3}}\leq 1$ as well. Did I go wrong somewhere? Or is there some way to solve it from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you have derived is true, but it's not enough to finish the problem.  Here is one way to do it:

We have $\sigma_2^2 = \alpha^2\beta^2 + \beta^2\gamma^2 +\alpha^2\gamma^2 + 2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)(\alpha\beta\gamma) = \alpha^2\beta^2 + \beta^2\gamma^2 +\alpha^2\gamma^2 + 2\sigma_1\sigma_3$.  Now we have that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\alpha^2} + \frac{1}{\beta^2} + \frac{1}{\gamma^2} \geq \frac{1}{\alpha\beta} + \frac{1}{\beta\gamma} +\frac{1}{\alpha\gamma}$, and multiplying this by $(\alpha\beta\gamma)^2$ we get $\alpha^2\beta^2 + \beta^2\gamma^2 +\alpha^2\gamma^2 \geq (\alpha+\beta+\gamma)(\alpha\beta\gamma) = \sigma_1\sigma_3$. Hence we get $\displaystyle \frac{b^2}{a^2} = \sigma_2^2 \geq 3\sigma_1\sigma_3 = \frac{3}{a^2}$, or $b^2 \geq 3$.  Therefore $b\geq\sqrt{3}$ as required.

Comment: more simple: $\sigma_2\ge  3\sqrt[3]{(\alpha\beta\gamma)^2}=3\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{a^4}} \iff b\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{a}} \ge \sqrt{3}$